# Python / Tracing - How to stop a function's execution (return from it ) from within a tracer

Tags: python, debugging, trace

Is there a way to return out of a function badfunc() using a tracer function tracer(), if we set sys.settrace(tracer).  I want to count the number of lines that badfunc() executes, and return out of it if it executes more than a given amount of lines.

e.g:

```
def badfunc():
    while True:
      import time
      time.sleep(1)

def tracer(*args):
    counter += 1
    if counter > MAX_NUMLINES:
        return_from_badfunc()
    return tracer

sys.settrace(tracer)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
import sys

MAX_NUMLINES = 7
counter = 0

class TooMuchLine(Exception):
    pass

def tracer(frame, event, arg):
    global counter
    if event == "line":
        counter += 1
        print "counter", counter
        if counter > MAX_NUMLINES:
             raise TooMuchLine()

    return tracer

def badfunc():
    while True:
      import time
      time.sleep(1)


sys.settrace(tracer)

print 'start'

try:
   badfunc()
except TooMuchLine:
   print 'stopped'

print 'done'
```

Output:

```
start
counter 1
counter 2
counter 3
counter 4
counter 5
counter 6
counter 7
counter 8
stopped
done
```

N.B: I hope that you already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692866/what-cool-hacks-can-be-done-using-sys-settrace/1693108#1693108) before playing with sys.settracer :)