# How to stop function mid run in Python

Tags: python

I have had many time where I had to stop a function in middle of a run, without having access to it, or it have hundreds of lines of code, where a if-check every line is not feasible, or it is struck somehow. That an be triggered by the code, itself.

I have used `sys.settrace` to get the task done, like in this MWE:

```
from threading import Event, Thread
import sys
import time

_stop = Event()


def _globaltrace(frame, event, arg):
    """The global trace call handler."""
    if event == 'call':
        return _localtrace
    else:
        return None


def _localtrace(frame, event, arg):
    """The local trace call handler."""
    global _stop
    if _stop.is_set():
        if event == 'line':
            raise Exception()
    return _localtrace


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def long_function():
        # The Function that need to be terminated before it ends.
        # That we _CAN'T_ change anything in.
        print("Long Function Started.")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    def simulate_external_input_callback():
        global _stop
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Kill signal received.")
        _stop.set()

    sys.settrace(_globaltrace)
    th = Thread(target=simulate_external_input_callback)
    th.start()

    try:
        long_function()
    except Exception:
        print("Long Function Killed.")
        # Try to do some cleanup.
    else:
        print("Long function ended normally.")
    print("The program continues, like nothing happened.")
    th.join()  # Just here for clean up.
```

And then have a something bound to set the event: `_stop.set()` when needed, by callback, or timer, and have a try-except to catch it.

But it is a nasty hack, and as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693108/9427691) say it is usually unnecessary. I believe them, I can just not wrap my head around another solution.

So I hope that someone would know the "right" solution, where there are not used the `sys.settrace`, to terminal the `long_function`.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you are looking to do? Right now it is very challenging to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I will try to come up with one, that will fit on the page.

Comment: Hope the update make it more clear, what I am trying to achieve.